# How do I print the success message

Tags: php, json

How do I print the success message in this **JSON** code using **PHP**

```
{
    "status": 0,

     " result":{
           "status":"success"
               }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$response = {"status":"success"};
$data = json_decode(response ,TRUE); //converts to associative array
if($data['status'] == 'success'){
echo 'You are success';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$result = json_decode('{
    "status": 0,

     " result":{
           "status":"success"
               }

}');

echo $result['result']['status'];
```

Answer (score -1):

- Convert this json to PHP Array using json_decode()
- Check the ['result']['status']
- if its equals to 'success'
- Then print some message